# Importing CSV file data from React to Node server and to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I need to read data from the CSV file and store the data to the database. I'm thinking of two ways I can do it:

1. Send the CSV file to the server (Node), read it there, store the data to the database and delete the file.
2. Read the CSV file in the frontend (React), send the data as JSON to the server and save it.

Which approach is better? I'm thinking the first one is harder, but what about security issues, because CSV file will contain users data like emails, names and passwords.